# jQuery way to initiate object from a plugin already initiated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question! :)

I am trying to use the jQuery plugin [RefineSlider](http://alexdunphy.github.com/refineslide/#tuning)!

My problem is that I am not a Javascript expert. What I wanted to accomplish is to add slides dynamically through an ajax call. The ajax call will return an html structure for a slide. But it has never work, because I think it's initiated at the DOM, and you cannot modify the slides on the fly!

Thank you, and have a great week! :)

Comment: if the API for the plugin doesn't support adding on the fly, best to find another plugin that does. I am asssuming you want to add images to existing slide show. Details aren't clear

Comment: Thank you @Charlietfl, the reason I want to use this plugin is because it support the cubic animation which is very sophisticated and impressive! And Yes, I will be adding the images to the slides as it becomes available on the server! Thank you again! :)

Comment: the plugin would need to be modified, which may not be trivial and it is highly unlikely you will get a fully tested solution here

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for baring with me here :) 
I am thinking now to find a premium service to modify the plugin for me. Can you direct me to one if you know? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

And if you add your function which implement the slider in this jquery function :

```
//This function will be called after an ajax
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
//The example to implement the slider
   $('.rs-slider').refineSlide({
        transition         : 'fade',
        transitionDuration : 7000,
        autoPlay           : true,
        keyNav             : false,
        delay              : 0,
        controls           : null
    });
});
```

But warn this function will be called for ALL ajax call. So you must add a test which control that you don't add more slider.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! The thing is that the content is dynamic. For example, I want to make a cubic tweets for a specefic twitter user. So, I will let the ajax call interval 10 seconds for example. Once there's a new tweet, it will append it in the current content, so that the cube animate to the new tweet! Something like this! 
I will test your solution, and let you know about it!

Comment: this didn't solve it unfortunately! Do you think there's another workaround this? Thank you again for your help!! :)